# How write text inside polygon leaflet draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
leafletMap.addLayer(drawnItems);

L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.polygon = 'Draw  polygon!';

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polyline: {
            metric: true
        },

        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false,
            showArea: true,
            drawError: {
                color: '#b00b00',
                timeout: 1000
            },

            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#bada55'
            }
        },
        circle: {

            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#662d91'
            }
        },
        circle:false,
        marker: false
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        remove: true
    }
});
```

Hello friends,
     i am using leaflet draw to draw polygon ,but after polygon is draw i want to show text inside that polygon, does that is possible.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a [bootbox] [1](http://bootboxjs.com/) dialog to ask for the text and [bindTooltip] [2](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tooltip) to put the text.

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    bootbox.prompt({title: "Any comment?", closeButton: false, callback: putTooltip});
        function putTooltip(result) {
            layer.bindTooltip(result, {'permanent': true, 'interactive': true});
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`L.Tooltip`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tooltip) with `permanent` set to `true`.

From the [Leaflet.Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/) github, this code snippet works with a popup:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'marker') {
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
    }

    editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
```

You can modify that code snippet to add a tooltip instead.

Comment: here when i user layer.bindPopup('abc'); its shows the popup me i click does its possible to make it show doesnt matter u click or not ..

Comment: That's why I suggested to modify the code. :) Use [the bindTooltip method (link)](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tooltip-bindtooltip): `layer.bindTooltip("my tooltip text", {permanent: true}).openTooltip();`